# ProGuard Configuration File is not working

Tags: java, android, proguard

Trying to use Proguard in an Project for Shrinking, Optimization and Obfuscation purposes.

I'm Using Following External libraries in my Project.

```
     - ActionBarSherlok : com.actionbarsherlock
        - SherlokNavigationDrawer : com.sherlock.navigationdrawer
        - GoogleplayLib : com.google.android.gms
        - ViewPagerIndicator : com.viewpagerindicator
        - MyAppPackage : ...

     - External Jar used are
       - HttpMime : 
       - GoogleAnalytics
       - Crittercism
       - UniversalImageLoader

# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# repackage and optimize
-repackageclasses "com.example.data"

# Keep a fixed source file attribute and all line number tables to get line
# numbers in the stack traces.
# You can comment this out if you're not interested in stack traces.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# keep annotations
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# keep the licencing service classes from Google
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
} 

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# an example on how to keep an entire package
# -keep class com.google.zxing.**
#############################################################################
#-keep class com.data.metro.services.**
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.**  { *; }
-keep class com.sherlock.navigationdrawer.**  { *; }
-keep class com.viewpagerindicator.**  { *; }

-libraryjars libs
-keep class crittercism.sdk.**  { *; }
-keep class crittercism.android.**  { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.entity.mime.**  { *; }
-keep class google.ads.**  { *; }
-keep class google.analytics**  { *; }
-keep class google.android.gms.**  { *; }
-keep class google.tagmanager.**  { *; }
-keep class com.nostra13.universalimageloader.** { *; }

#############################################################################
# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**

# an example if you don't want to be warned about missing libraries
# -dontwarn javax.naming.**

#############################################################################

# remove logging, note that this removes ALL logging, including the 
# Log.e statements
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    *;
}

#-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
#-optimizationpasses 5
#-allowaccessmodification
#-dontpreverify
```

After Exporting the application it doesn't work at all.
Reason being are code are not shrinking properly it removes some used code as well, I found this when I saw the code using dex2jar and jdgui.

Needs suggestions, What changes are required in this proguard.cfg Cofiguration file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add lines in your Proguard file to tell to shrink all useful code .

So to include SherLock codes you will need to add all useful class in Proguard as

```
-keep class com.example.classname.**{
       *;
 }

 -keep interface  com.example.classname.**{
      *;
 }
```

and to include Jars use below lines

```
 -injars bin/classes
 -injars libs
 -outjars bin/classes-processed.jar

 -libraryjars /libs/nameofjarfile.jar
```

like these above lines.

Hope it will help you .
Please try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import the libraries for a correct compilation. Try with the folowing parameters (for instance):

```
-injars libary1.jar
-libraryjars '/Java/jre6/lib/rt.jar'
```